# Como realizar la suma de datos por semana en SQL Server

Tags: sql

Buen dia,

Tengo la siguiente consulta en SQL

`SELECT DATE_TIME, DEP_ACCEPTED, DATEDIFF( MINUTE, START_TIME, FINISH_TIME ) AS DOWNTIME, STATUS_ISSUE FROM ISSUES WHERE STATUS_ISSUE = 'CLOSE' AND DEP_ACCEPTED = 'ROBOTS'`

Y da como resultado esto:

```
DATE_TIME   DEP     DOWNTIME   STATUS
2021-09-22  ROBOTS      6        CLOSE
2021-09-30  ROBOTS      11       CLOSE
2021-10-04  ROBOTS      2        CLOSE
2021-10-14  ROBOTS      3        CLOSE
```

Entonces mi pregunta es, ¿se puede agrupar esta informacion por semana y sumar el Downtime?

Para que quede la informacion como

```
Week     Dep     Downtime
 10     Robots      50
 11     Robots      40
 12     Robots      30
```

Agradeceria que me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Esos números en la columna week, a qué corresponden? Semana de qué? Los asignas tú?

Comment: Te falta especificar para que motor de base de datos estas trabajando

Comment: Seria los numeros de la semana del año, y el motor de la bd es SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolvi,

Por si alguien mas le sirve aqui esta:

Y el departamento lo busco en base al where

```
SELECT DATEPART(WEEK, DATE_TIME) AS WEEK, SUM( DATEDIFF( MINUTE, START_TIME, FINISH_TIME ) ) AS DOWNTIME
FROM ISSUES WHERE STATUS_ISSUE = 'CLOSE' AND DEP_ACCEPTED = 'ROBOTS'
GROUP BY DATEPART(WEEK, DATE_TIME)
```

Y me da el resultado que buscaba:

```
Week  Downtime
 39      6
 40     11
 41      2
```